# Añadir texto a pdf firmado digitalmente, usando itextsharp y vb.net (sin perder la firma)

Tags: pdf, itextsharp, firma-digital

Tengo un pdf firmado digitalmente. Tengo que añadir un texto al pdf, el problema que tengo es que tras añadir el texto, desaparece la firma digital. Os pongo el código que he usado.

```html
 Sub colocarTextoSello(ByRef contentByte As PdfContentByte, bf As BaseFont, text As String, PosX As Single, PosY As Single, rot As Single, SizeText As Single, colortexto As iTextSharp.text.BaseColor, TipoLetra As Char)
        If TipoLetra = "S" Then 'simple
            bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED)          
        ElseIf TipoLetra = "N" Then 'negrita
            bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED)
        End If
        contentByte.BeginText()
        contentByte.SetColorFill(colortexto)
        contentByte.SetFontAndSize(bf, SizeText)
        contentByte.ShowTextAligned(3, text, PosX, PosY, rot) 'texto rotado 90º, para ponerlo en verti (1,texto, ancho, alto, angulo rotacion)
        contentByte.EndText()
    End Sub
```

Cualquier idea será bienvenida.
Gracias

Comment: La idea de la firma digital es precisamente que no se pueda modificar el documento sin que se destruya la firma. Imagina que firmas un contrato en el que después se pueda modificar el precio y que parezca que has firmado el contrato con el precio nuevo... Si se modifica el documento, hay que firmar de nuevo.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario @SJuan76. En los documentos que veo firmados, normalmente, se invalida la firma (aspa roja), pero no desaparece, y eso es lo que pretendo reproducir, pero con este código desaparece la firma.